# Java Swing: JTextArea columns question

Tags: java, swing

How do I put the text in specific columns with jTextArea?

```
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        jTextArea1.setColumns(4);
        jTextArea1.insert(price, 0);    //column 1
        jTextArea1.insert(cost, 0);    //column 2
        jTextArea1.insert(quantity, 0);       //column etc..
        jTextArea1.insert(itemName, 0);
        jTextArea1.insert("\n", 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use a JTable.

But if you really want to use a text cmponent you can use a JTextPane and play with tabs. See my example in [JTextPane Tab Size](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=585006).

Answer (score 3):

There are situations when the (mighty) JTable is too much.

If you just want a JLabel/ JTextArea like component with some columns use a HTML-Table in a JTextPane or in a JEditorPane:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;

public class ColumnsInJTextPane
{

  public ColumnsInJTextPane()
  {
    double price = 124.75;
    int quantity = 3;
    String itemName = " iPad";

    JTextPane t = new JTextPane();
    t.setContentType( "text/html" );

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder( 150 );
    text.append( "<html><body>" );
    text.append( "<table border='0' style='margin:4px 2px 12px 6px' width='100%'>" );

    text.append( "<tr>" + "<td width='30' align='left' valign='top' style='margin-right:8px'>" );
    text.append( price );
    text.append( "</td>" );

    text.append( "<td align='left' valign='top' style='margin-right:8px'>" );
    text.append( itemName );
    text.append( "</td>" );

    text.append( "<td width='20' align='left' valign='top' style='margin-right:8px'>" );
    text.append( quantity );
    text.append( "</td>" + "</tr>" );

    text.append( "<tr>" + "<td>" );
    text.append( price * 4 );
    text.append( "</td>" );

    text.append( "<td>" );
    text.append( (((Boolean) itemName.equals( itemName )).toString().concat( itemName )) );
    text.append( "</td>" );

    text.append( "<td>" );
    text.append( quantity / 2 );
    text.append( "</td>" + "</tr>" );

    text.append( "</table>" );
    text.append( "</body></html>" );

    t.setText( text.toString() );

    //to get a consistent (body) appearance use the font from the Label using a CSS rule (instead of the value in javax.swing.text.html.default.css)
    Font font = UIManager.getFont( "Label.font" );
    String bodyRule =
    "body { font-family: " + font.getFamily() + "; " + "font-size: " + font.getSize() + "pt; }";
    ((HTMLDocument) t.getDocument()).getStyleSheet().addRule( bodyRule );

    JDialog d = new JDialog();
    d.add( t );
    d.pack();
    d.setVisible( true );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    new ColumnsInJTextPane();
  }

}
```

There are some tweaks and tricks in this example which demonstrate how evil HTML really is ;-)

- the trimming of spaces is utilized
- the second column is growing/ shrinking with the JDialog size because of the omitted width in its td-Tag
- css margins have been thrown in for no special reason
- for a consistent appearance the font of the JLabel has to be fetched from the UIManager and set via CSS
- if you reduce the width of the JDialog the text in the second column is nicely word-wrapped
   *(ooh, wait! this is a **nice** feature of HTML)*

Answer (score 1):

A column refers to a character, so if columns = 4 it means the width will be 4 characters wide.

Comment: oh, is there anyway to separate my text into columns or indent it so that it appears evenly in my textarea?

Comment: Use a JTable instead, or multiple JTextAreas

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inserting your text at the same position ! 
Replace 0 by whatever column you want the text to be at. And see the result

EDIT:

Column size means amount of characters, not words.
As commented, have a look at [JTable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

Comment: Ya i dont really get the position property. basiclly i want to set the price, cost, quantity, name into individual columns

Comment: You are not using the right Swing component then.
You better have a look at JTable. which have proper column. You simply set up an array containing all your values, each element of the array to be placed in its corresponding column.

Comment: ya i was thinking about using that, but i was unsure how to do it in a while statement since im reading in values from a file.

Comment: See other answer about JTable. They are not as easy to use as a simple JTextArea. See several examples, you will get it. JTable is what you need. The fact that you read values from a file, database or other is independent to what you use to display them.